# Using iSeries cryptographic APIs with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, ibm-midrange

I'm attempting to encrypt comms between a C# client and iSeries server but am experiencing some issues. I'm trying to use Diffie Hellman to create a shared secret but the shared secret is not matching.

I'm using Bouncy Castle in the C# and the QC3* APIs on the iSeries. The steps are:

1. C# client generates DH parameters and sends them to the server along with the client public key.
2. C service program decodes the parameters and calls QC3GENDK to create server public key.
3. Server calls QC3CALDS with the client public key to generate the shared secret.
4. Server public key is sent back to the client.
5. Bouncy Castle Basic DH agreement initialized with the client private key
6. Client calls CalculateAgreement with the DHPublicKeyParameters generated from the parameters in step 1 and the server public key.

The way the data is sent back and forth is by converting to HEX strings and decoding on each side. Conversion between EBCDIC and ASCII occurs in a service program on the iSeries. So for example, the client public key is converted as follows:

1. Public key (as BigInteger) is converted to unsigned byte array, e.g. 256 -> { 1, 0 }
2. Byte array is converted to a string of HEX characters, e.g. { 1, 0 } -> "0100")
3. HEX string sent across to iSeries.
4. HEX string converted to a character array of length 64 via the following (RPG) code:

   ```
   cvtch( %Addr (@clientKey ): %Addr(data4): 128);
   eval @clientKey = %Subst( @clientKey: 1: 64);
   ```

   where:

   data4 - HEX string

   @clientKey - 64A receiver variable

and the server key is converted to Hex via:

1. Convert to hex string on the server

   ```
   cvthc ( %Addr( @serverKeyHex ): %Addr(@serverKey): 128);
   eval @serverKeyHex = %Subst(@serverKeyHex: 1: 128);
   ```

   where:

   @serverKey is the 64A serverKey

   @serverKeyHex is the 128A receiver variable
2. Send the HEX string across to C# client
3. Interpret the HEX string as a BigInteger via

   var serverKey = new BigInteger(serverHex, 16);

So, the shared secret isn't matching but I don't know if this is to do with how I'm interpreting the keys or sending them across. Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: 
To give a concrete example:

In the RPG debugger I can see:
[image: RPG debugger]

For a Client public key whose hex is : 4F58E1463B66CAAC1BDD35C518A6B76E52E0464E635050B50C87329CFC4C154B8EA07B12AF0E0B9754D5331235805CF59ABE1BB500B4906BD03BCF6C7861E2E8

EDIT2 (More info):
API calls on the iSeries (in C) can be seen in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/ximenean/a0a9193b776f301997bb

Comment: At point #3 -- `HEX string sent across to iSeries.` How are values "sent" back and forth? Also, can we see the API calls on your iSeries?

Comment: @user2338816 I've added a gist of the API calls. Data is sent across over TCP/IP - a service program listens on a socket and converts the raw bytes to an EBCDIC string.

Comment: I'll look over your APIs. And to emphasize what others have said, this is **not** EBCDIC data (nor ASCII). Care must be taken to treat it as binary data, strings of bits that cannot have any type of encoding nor other conversions done. If it is the same at the bit level on a PC as it is in your iSeries debug, so far, so good.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what conversion is happening on the C# side, but the RPG / MI side is converting from string to string.  Take an EBCDIC string 'ABCD'  This is a perfectly valid 4 byte binary number, as well as a perfectly valid 4 byte character.  In EBCDIC CCSID 37 (US English), this string has the code points x'C1C2C3C4'.

CVTCH will generate the following string: 'C1C2C3C4'  That is, it takes a 4 character string and 'converts' it to an 8 character string.  In CCSID 37, that is x'C3F1C3F2C3F3C3F4'.  If you send this string off to a client which interprets this in ASCII, it will be interpreted quite differently, as ASCII's code points x'C1C2C3C4' is the ASCII string 'ÁÂÃÄ'

You probably want to translate it to ASCII before sending it from the IBM side.  'C1C2C3C4' would become '41424344' and so on.

Comment: Actually, ASCII doesn't even have code points C1 through C4. You probably mean Latin-1 or ISO 8859-1.

Comment: Point granted.  The idea I really wanted to get across was the notion that sending 'hex' back and forth is not some sort of single, absolute, set-in-stone character set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the EBCDIC -> ASCII conversion does happen. I stupidly forgot to mention this. I'm not sure if it's still an issue though. For example, say I have a public key in the client that converts to hex as "4F58E1463B66CAAC1BDD35C518A6B76E52E0464E635050B50C87329CFC4C154B8EA07B12AF0E0B9754D5331235805CF59ABE1BB500B4906BD03BCF6C7861E2E8" then I can look at the data in the debugger in the RPG and see the same bytes. (See my edited question)

Comment: BigInteger wants the byte array to be little-endian.  So it would convert {5,4,3,2,1} to the integer 4328719365  IBM i is big-endian.  If the API returns 12345 as the shared key, the bytes would be in the wrong order for BigInteger to convert 'back' to the 64 byte 'integer'.  Are these conversions needed because it's not a direct socket connexion (and the string needs to be escaped)?

Comment: Is it just as simple as reversing the byte array of the client key before converting to the HEX string so {5,4,3,2,1} would go to {1,2,3,4,5}? And then the same with the server key - convert to hex then to byte array and reverse?

Comment: It might be that simple.  I don't have C# loaded so I can't try it myself.  Why not just pass the 64 byte keys back and forth 'as-is', instead of converting to integer and then expanding it to hex?  Is it because the transport mechanism doesn't like binary data?

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. Originally I was just sending the bytes back and forth but they are subject to EBCDIC conversion and I wanted to rule out that it was that which was causing it to break. In fact the library that I use works with strings and converts to bytes to send across the wire so I was creating a UTF8 encoded string in the C# from the bytes and sending it across where it was converted to EBCDIC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64652/discussion-between-andrew-jones-and-buck-calabro).

Comment: I didn't quite follow how {5, 4, 3, 2, 1} becomes 4328719365, but anyway, I've posted some thoughts in the chat regarding endianness.

Comment: Microsoft example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd268207%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I'm using the BouncyCastle implementation of BigInteger. I've just done a quick comparison and it seems that the BouncyCastle implementation returns a Big Endian byte array. Please follow up in the chat to avoid this comment thread getting too long.